# RabbitMQ IOError Socket Closed when changing settings

Tags: rabbitmq

I have several VMs all getting messages from a node running RabbitMQ.

I've hit a bottleneck of the default settings so I'm starting to tweak it to get better results.

I've added

> CONFIGFILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq

and set the following rabbitmq.config

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners,[{"0.0.0.0", 5672}]},

    {tcp_listen_options, [
                          {nodelay, true}
                          ]}
  ]}
].
```

This is just one of the suggestions from the website.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html

Without the config file, everything runs ok, but when adding the file I keep getting IOError Socket Closed.

Is there anything in the configuration file which is causing the socket to be closed?

Comment: there's no question here, only statements of what is happening. is there a specific question you wish to ask? also, is it the rabbitmq server or connection publishers or consumers that are getting the IOError?

Comment: Edited the original post. But to answer your quesiton, it's the publisher who is getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found here http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2012-January/017138.html

After adding those settings to the config file, connection could be established again.